# Angular6 Decoupling formValidation from the controller

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

So at the moment I'm using Angular6 Reactive form module to create forms in addition to the Validation module.

```
form = new FormGroup({
groupOne: new FormGroup({
example: new FormControl('', Validation.required)
})
})
```

Naturally this is a very basic implementation of this but this becomes really quite verbose when the validation methods start to stack up especially on a large form, is there a more prudent way to handle this, i.e decoupling the validation/rules from the controller?

Cheers.

Comment: you can optimise the validation part in view as well:

such as :
<input required type="any" formControlName="example"/>

Comment: But you have multiple validation like pattern validation on custom validation which is need depended you need to include in it.

Comment: Yes. you can optimise in view using common class. for validation

Comment: If I was to use a common class for validation how would I go about integrating it with the the formGroup/controls would I submit the validation on lets say a submit button? Or is there a way I can have the validation running async?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the FormBuilder feature. That reduces the amount of code required to define the FormGroup.

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

this.productForm = this.fb.group({
  productName: ['', [Validators.required,
                     Validators.minLength(3),
                     Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  productCode: ['', Validators.required],
  starRating: ['', NumberValidators.range(1, 5)],
  tags: this.fb.array([]),
  description: ''
});
```

`fb` in the above code is the FormBuilder.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using the library [`ng-form-rules`](https://github.com/cknightdevelopment/ng-form-rules/). It is an awesome library for creating all different kinds of forms with validation logic decoupled from the component (and re-useable). They have [great documentation](https://github.com/cknightdevelopment/ng-form-rules/wiki), [examples](https://github.com/cknightdevelopment/ng-form-rules/wiki/Examples-List), and a [video that show a bunch of its functionality](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eL3Gp1cGBJQ).

You can [check out their README](https://github.com/cknightdevelopment/ng-form-rules/) for some high level info and a basic example.